# React Geocode package returns fulfilled Promise object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, google-geocoder

I have a piece of state which is meant to receive user location on page load.

```
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState({
    lat: null,
    lng: null,
    userAddress: ''
  })
```

I have created a getAddress function which is meant to return a string value of an address based on coordinates using the react Geocode npm package

```
  const getAddress = async (lat, lng) => {
    try {
      const res = await Geocode.fromLatLng(lat, lng)
      const address = res.results[0].formatted_address;
      return address

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }

  }
```

my getUserLocation function is run in a useEffect on page load

```
  const getUserLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }

  const showPosition = (position) => {
    setUserLocation({
      ...userLocation,
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude,
      userAddress: getAddress(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
    })
  }
```

my userLocation object is returning as follows:

```
USER LOCATION 
{lat: 43.829601, lng: -79.470408, userAddress: Promise}
lat: 43.829601
lng: -79.470408
userAddress: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "126 Seabreeze Ave, Thornhill, ON L4J 9H1, Canada"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I would like the promise result value to be returned and nothing else obviously. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: `getAddress` is async, so you'd need to await it in order to assign its response and it not be a promise

Comment: @BrianThompson is it not async at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because async functions return a promise, calling one will give you back the promise, not the result.

Here you are calling `getAddress` directly:

```js
userAddress: getAddress(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
```

But if you want the result, you'll have to make `showPosition` async, and `await` the result from `getAddress`:

```js
const showPosition = async (position) => {
    setUserLocation({
      ...
      ...
      ...
      userAddress: await getAddress(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
    })
  }
```

Comment: amazing thanks mate

Comment: Is this same result possible within JSX?

<h3>Address: {async () => await getAddress(service.location.lat, service.location.lng)}</h3>

Comment: try it and see! but that's just a function declaration - functions aren't valid react children, and anyway it wouldn't do anything unless you actually called it. you couldn't do some kind of async IIFE `(async () => await ...)()`, because that would just return a promise which you would then need to await anyway... the point: you can't `await` or `.then` directly inside a component because components can't be asynchronous.